# MySQL - Generate random unique code if column is NULL

Tags: mysql, random, alter-table

I have a table col called `unique_id` which is set to `NULL` by default.

How can I "create a patch" and alter the table so when the `unique_id` is `NULL` to generate a random code (contains sting like this EE7B35CB25D24E34D7B5DE2A)

```
ALTER TABLE `projects`
CHANGE `unique_id` char('24') = RAND()
COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NULL 
AFTER `status`;
```

Comment: You can set auto increment to your unique id

Comment: the `unique_id` is not like `id` which is primary key, in addition it could have letters and number - I'm going to update the question as I did a mistake

Comment: Trigger is a good way then which @Rahul mention as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I see (since you need a unique `random` number) is using `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. Check for `NULL` and update the column with random number using `RAND()` function probably.

Using `RAND()` with `DEFAULT` is not possible since `DEFAULT` expects the argument to be static / constant and not any expression (Thought of making the pointer, if this comes to your mind as a possible solution).

Comment: did an update, its not nessecarry numbers, it can be a string like this EE7B35CB25D24E34D7B5DE2A

Comment: @Lykos, in that case also, you can follow the same approach except that you can't use `RAND()` function but your own UDF probably which will generate the custom random string.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correct your answer, but what if I remove the default option??

Comment: @Lykos, your `default` option is useless in this scenario. Remove it. you will have to get it done through a trigger as already said.